# Azure Speech Recognition Keyword C#

Tags: c#, windows, azure, visual-studio-2019

Estoy utilizando Azure, Speech Recognition la idea es hacer un asistente virtual que despierte con un KeyWord, cree la frase con Speech Studio pero no encuentro en la documentación como debo utilizar dicho modelo entrenado, la descargué y tiene una extensión .table. ¿Alguien que haya trabajado con esta funcionalidad?